# mount: unknown filesystem type 'cifs'

Tags: mount, fstab, automount, cifs, nas

For some reason, I can mount my NAS using cifs as follows:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //10.0.0.210/data -o username=xxxxxxxxxxxxx,password=xxxxxxxxxxx,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755 /mnt/nas
```

But when I enter this into my fstab:

```
//10.0.0.210    /mnt/nas   cifs  username=xxxxxxxxxxxxx,password=xxxxxxxxxxxxx,rw,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755
```

And I run this:

```
sudo mount -a
```

I get this:

```
mount: unknown filesystem type 'cifs'
```

Any help here would be awesome.  Thanks

Comment: I think you forgot to add /data in the fstab entry

Answer (score 1):

The mobule is probably not loaded.

```
sudo modprobe cifs
```

*updated with the module name

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and other problems with CIFS, and it seems on e.g. ubuntu 18.04 you should also install `cifs-utils` to better support SMBv3 for best security.

`apt-get install cifs-utils`

I also suggest you to put credentials in a file. E.g. /root/.smbfile

```
username=<user>
password=<password>
```

and `chmod 600 /root/.smbfile`

Then you `/etc/fstab` could be this instead

```
//10.0.0.210/data /mnt/nas cifs credentials=/root/.smbfile,nounix,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755`
```